# Lightbox 2 with ember js and Froala editor (image preview on click)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, lightbox2, froala

I am using ember js as my front end MVC. I have a Question and Answers module which is similar to stack overflow where there are 2 fields one for the title and the other for the description.

Since the description is a text area and I have plugged it with [Froala wysiwug edito](http://editor.froala.com/)r.

Now I get the content typed in the froala text editor in ember by using

```
var editorText = $('.froala-element');
var desciption = editorText.html();
```

in the ember controller.

For example, if I console log what comes from the textarea

```
<p><img class="fr-fin" data-fr-image-preview="false" alt="Image title" src="/img/4ad38ae5b4a73cbad30987ac441075998d1e6b35.jpg" width="300"></p><p><br></p>
```

And I save this string in the database. All works good.

Now I want to use [lightbox plugin](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

And as you notice, to make use of the plugin the **image needs to be wrapped inside an anchor tag and added few data-lightbox attributes**

Since I am stroing the image tag markup in the database, what is the best approach wrap the image inside the `anchor tag`

I got 2 options - 
1) Before saving the image in the database, do a pattern match with javascript and find the image and wrap it inside an anchor tag.
2) In the `didInsertElement` hook of ember view, find all the images on the page and perform a `dom manuplation` and wrap the images inside anchor tag.

Is there any other way I could get this working ? Need some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should get the HTML inside the editable area using the methods that are available in the editor, in this case `getHTML` method http://editor.froala.com/examples/getHTML. It is preferable to do so because there are some cleanups which the getHTML method does and it's good to make them.

```
$('#edit').editable('getHTML', false, true);
```

You can use the RegEx approach that you suggested, but you have to take into consideration not to wrap it twice. Another option would be to do that using jQuery which is easier.

```
var editorText = $('#edit').editable('getHTML', false, true);
var $div = $('<div>').html(editorText);

// Wrap image.
$div.find('img').each (function (index, img) {
  var $img = $(img);

  // Check if image is already wrapped in your anchor tag.
  if (!$img.parents('a.your_anchor_selector').length) {
    $img.wrap('<a class="your_anchor"></a>');
  }
});

var description = $div.html();
```